# Finding out what folders and files take the most space on a Windows computer?

Tags: windows, memory, memory-management, operating-system, diskspace

1) What good software out there already exists that allows one (preferably visually) see what folders and files are taking the most space on one's computer (Windows Vista compatible)

2) Say I wanted to write a this program myself, what opensource tools out there can I use to get started?

Thanks!

Comment: I've always used [JDiskReport](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/jdiskreport/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) You can try WinDirStat: http://windirstat.info/

2) I don't think you need open source tools, you could write it in Java or .NET just by using what is already provided with the languages.

Comment: Thanks!...what key libraries in Java would be helpful?

Comment: You could use the default `java.io.*` namespace. Or if you want a library, the IO part of the Apache Commons lib can help you, check the `FileUtils` class (it has a `sizeOfDirectory` method) at http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are plenty of them. [For example check out these..](http://www.technize.com/5-free-tools-to-list-hard-drive-contents-graphically/)

Answer (score 0):

I use Sequoia View http://www.snapfiles.com/get/sequoia.html. As to the second part of your question I don't know sorry.